# Why using grid-template-areas with grid areas of the same class but different selectors are displayed in reverse order?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using css grid and I am experiencing a weird issue.

As you can see in the code below. I have a parent grid, `homepage__section__medical-types__content` which declares the

```
grid-template-areas:
    "blue"
    "content1"
    "green"
    "content2";
```

and  four rows. *content1* and *content2* are assigned respectively to:

```
homepage__heading__info:first-child
```

and

```
homepage__heading__info:nth-child(2)
```

but why are they displayed in reverse order as they are declared? What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: lavenderblush;
  height: auto;
  width: 320px;
}

.homepage__section__medical-types {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: ". medic .";
  grid-template-columns: 48px 1fr 16px;
}

.homepage__section__medical-types__content {
  grid-area: medic;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  "blue"
  "content1"
  "green"
  "content2";
  grid-template-rows: 250px 1fr 250px 1fr;
}

.homepage__heading-box {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.homepage__heading-box--blue {
  grid-area: blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #669DD6, #ADDAF1);
}

.homepage__heading-box--green {
  grid-area: green;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #51CEA2, #97DCC6);
}

.homepage__heading__info {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.homepage__heading__info:first-child {
  grid-area: content1;
}

.homepage__heading__info:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: content2;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="homepage__section__medical-types">
    <div class="homepage__section__medical-types__content">
      <div class="homepage__heading-box homepage__heading-box--blue"></div>
      <div class="homepage__heading__info">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="homepage__heading-box homepage__heading-box--green"></div>
      <div class="homepage__heading__info">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I have noticed that just commenting out `grid-area: content1;` and `grid-area: content2;` but keeping the same the parent grid-template-area, the corresponding elements are displayed in the correct order. I am more confused then before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the purpose of the [**`nth-child()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo-class.

To be clear, this is your HTML:

```
<div class="homepage__section__medical-types__content">
   <div class="homepage__heading-box homepage__heading-box--blue"></div>
   <div class="homepage__heading__info"><p>1</p></div>
   <div class="homepage__heading-box homepage__heading-box--green"></div>
   <div class="homepage__heading__info"><p>2</p></div>
</div>
```

And this is your CSS:

```
.homepage__heading__info:first-child {
   grid-area: content1;
}

.homepage__heading__info:nth-child(2) {
   grid-area: content2;
   color: red
}
```

So, `:first-child` applies to the first child *among all siblings*. `.homepage__heading__info` is never the first child among all siblings. So with `:first-child` applied, it is simply ignored. If you search for this selector in dev tools, it doesn't even appear, because its target doesn't exist.

With `.homepage__heading__info:nth-child(2)`, this actually applies to the second child among all siblings, which happens to be the first `.homepage__heading__info` (the item with text "1"). The selector applies grid area "content2" to this element, sending it to the bottom, as per `grid-template-areas`.

```
grid-template-areas:
   "blue"
   "content1"
   "green"
   "content2"
```

The element with text "2" is auto-placed in the unoccupied row, which happens to be row 2 (again, `content1` doesn't exist). As a result, 2 comes before 1.

---

> EDIT: I have noticed that just commenting out `grid-area: content1` and `grid-area: content2` but keeping the same the parent `grid-template-area`, the corresponding elements are displayed in the correct order. I am more confused then before.

Without the grid areas, the algorithm places the specified items per `grid-template-areas` (in this case, that would be only "blue" and "green") and the remaining items are auto-placed into existing rows in source order.

Comment: Omg, I am feeling so stupid. Of course the problem is the misuse of nth-child selector. I kind lost myself in a glass of water! Thank you for the detailed answer; I've marked it as accepted! Just a question: if I use :nth-of-type instead it is not a really alternative solution right? :nth-of-type works only to elements and not classes, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you switched the elements with class `homepage__heading__info` to their own unique element type, then you could use `:nth-of-type()`.